# Wrap entire app in single ErrorBoundary (react-error-boundary)

Tags: reactjs, react-error-boundary

We have an `App.js` file in React, and I would like to add an error boundary that wraps around the majority of routes. The App.js file broadly looks like this:

```
import { ErrorBoundary } from 'react-error-boundary';


function ErrorFallback({ error }) {
    return (
        <div role='alert'>
            <p>Something went wrong:</p>
            <pre style={{ color: 'red' }}>{error.message}</pre>
        </div>
    );
}

function App() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Navbar />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/page1' component={comp1} />
                <Route exact path='/page2' component={comp2} />
                <Route exact path='/page3' component={comp3} />
                <Route exact path='/page4' component={comp4} />
                <Route exact path='/page5' component={comp5} />
                <Route exact path='/page6' component={comp6} />
                <Route component={NoMatch} />
            </Switch>
            <Footer />
        <React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

We are trying to use 1 `ErrorBoundary` to wrap all of the routes inside the `<switch>`. Note that the last route in the switch is a `NoMatch` component that renders if none of the other Routes render. If I try to render the `ErrorBoundary` inside of the `<Switch>`, as such:

```
<React.Fragment>
    <Navbar />
    <Switch>
        <ErrorBoundary Fallback={ErrorFallback}>
            <Route exact path='/page1' component={comp1} />
            ...
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
        </ErrorBoundary>
    </Switch>
    ...
```

then for some reason, the `NoMatch` component always renders. And if I drag the `NoMatch` Route one row down (below the `</ErrorBoundary>`), then the `NoMatch` Route never renders (even when it should). On the other hand, if I wrap the `</ErrorBoundary>` around the entire `<Switch>`:

```
    <ErrorBoundary Fallback={ErrorFallback}>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/page1' component={comp1} />
            ...
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
       </Switch>
    </ErrorBoundary>
```

..then the `ErrorBoundary` and the `NoMatch` both do seem to work. My question is - is this last code block the correct way to wrap multiple Routes in a React App.js file inside of a single ErrorBoundary?

Edit: I understand that there are tradeoffs to wrapping all of these routes inside of a single error boundary. For this instance, I am okay with this tradeoff, and the single error-boundary is by design (for now).

Comment: Did you found anything? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: Yes I'm wrapping the ErrorBoundary around pretty much everything, just to have the broad ErrorBoundary coverage. At some point I may make more granular error boundaries for other components

Comment: Figured out the same, thanks a lot for your input, @Canovice!